# Fast idempotent Ansible apt deb url

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

It looks like like command `apt install https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases/download/v12.9.3/draw.io-amd64-12.9.3.deb` could take long time each time when is invoked even if the package is installed already. It is literally downloads the package each time.

And yes, with ansible is **idempotent**, with status changed: no.

```yaml
- name: Install a drawio-desktop .deb package
  apt:
    deb: https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases/download/v12.9.3/draw.io-amd64-12.9.3.deb
  when: ansible_facts['lsb']['id'] == "Ubuntu"
  tags:
    - debug
    - not-macos
```

Is there any short way to skip download if package installed ?

Ideally will be to say in `name` that I want to install `draw.io` if not installed from `deb: url` else consider things installed.

```yaml
- name: Install a drawio-desktop .deb package
  apt:
    name: draw.io
    deb: https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases/download/v12.9.3/draw.io-amd64-12.9.3.deb
```

but is not working like that

```
TASK [desktop : Install a drawio-desktop .deb package] *********
fatal: [tuxedo]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "parameters are mutually exclusive: deb|package|upgrade"}
```

Any suggestion on a lighter solution to speed up the task?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior seems to be intended according the parameter [deb](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#parameter-deb)

> Ansible will attempt to download deb before installing.

and the current source of [apt.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/apt.py#L1349).

So you may have a look into the module [`package_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html)

```yaml
- name: Gather Package Facts
  package_facts:
    manager: apt # default ["auto"]
```

as well a [Conditional Example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html#examples) of

```yaml
  when: "ansible_facts['lsb']['id'] == 'Ubuntu' and 'draw.io' not in ansible_facts.packages"
```

**Credits to**

- [How to get the installed apt packages with Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58647018/6771046)

**Further Q&A**

- [Ansible: Do task if apt package is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754155/)

---

An other approach might be to have the [latest](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases/latest/) package always internally (cached) available and provide a `.list` file for the native package manager, pointing to the internal repository URL (file share).

By doing this, you could then just use

```yaml
- name: Install a drawio-desktop .deb package
  apt:
    name: draw.io
    state: latest
```

without further checks. This will address required updates too.